# React SetState not updating in a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, react-state

i'm working on a MERN project and it's been weeks that i have an issue with React states.
I use a state to display a Popup or not.

That's the way i'm displaying it:

```
{OptionsPopUpState
    ? <OptionsPopUp func={OptionsPopUpfunc} name={OptionsPopUpData.name} id={OptionsPopUpData.id} shared={OptionsPopUpData.shared} languageQuestion={OptionsPopUpData.languageQuestion} languageAnswer={OptionsPopUpData.languageAnswer} />
    : ""
}
```

The function passed in props is the one which hide or display it depending on the state.

Here's the function:

```
const OptionsPopUpfunc = (event)=>{

    if(event){
      event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    let clicked = event.target
    let attributes = JSON.parse( clicked.getAttribute("data-info") ) //get data passed (id and name)
    if(attributes){
      SetOptionsPopUpData({"name":attributes.name, "id":attributes.id, "shared": attributes.shared, "languageQuestion": attributes.languageQuestion, "languageAnswer": attributes.languageAnswer}) //set data to pass in props for the popup
    }


    if(OptionsPopUpState){
      SetOptionsPopUpState(false)
      console.log("New state "+OptionsPopUpState)
      refresh();     //refresh when close with delay

    }
    else{
      console.log("display")
      SetOptionsPopUpState(true);
    }
  }
```

I don't get why it is not working because i use exactly the same code for an other popup and it works perfectly.
On the top of it, when i print the state just after having changed it, no change...

Edit:
Refresh function

```
const refresh = ()=>{
    

      fetch('/get_flashcards', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            'token': cookies.token
        })
      }).then((response)=>{
        if(response.ok){
          
          response.json().then((data)=>{

            var flashcard = data.successfull.map(flashcardSerie=>{
              return(
              <div class="relative w-80 py-3 bg-white-ctm mx-auto inset-x-0 rounded-md backdrop-blur-4xl p-2 flex flex-row" onClick={()=>{redirect(flashcardSerie._id)}}>
                <h2 class="text-white font-medium pl-4 text-left">{flashcardSerie.name}</h2>
                <img onClick={OptionsPopUpfunc} data-info={JSON.stringify({'name':flashcardSerie.name,'id':flashcardSerie._id, 'shared':true, 'languageQuestion':flashcardSerie.languageQuestion, 'languageAnswer':flashcardSerie.languageAnswer}) } class="absolute right-4 w-6 h-6" src={IconMore}/>
              </div>)
            })

            SetFlashCards(flashcard)
            SetInit(true)

          })

        }else if(response.status === 403){

          document.location = "login"

        }


      })


  }
```

Does anyone understand the problem's origin ?
Thanks

Comment: _"On the top of it, when i print the state just after having changed it, no change"_: because changes to state tend to be batched and asynchronous. You should use `useEffect` to inspect the changes.

Comment: `On the top of it, `,, yeah that's normal.   What does `refresh` do exactly, do bear in mind this will execute immediately even before the popup shows,  your comment says something about close, but it's not something you know at this point.

Comment: @Keith i have just disabled the refresh call and it works. I'm not sure to understand ...